# Compiled document differs accross two computers

Tags: compiling, texlive-2016

Good day,

I experience an odd behaviour while compiling a document on two different computers. The resulting document differs extensively: on Laptop the pdf is about 300 pages long. On my PC it has 320 pages. The document is synchronised by cloud and is exactly the same version. Both computer run on Ubuntu 16.04 and `texlive 2016`, installed manually from tug.org. My texlive installation is ‘vanilla’ i.e. I have not changed any files in it. I use `texstudio` on both. I only sync `*.tex` files – `*.aux` and other files that are created in the compiling process are left out and generated freshly on each PC.

I compared the two log files that are created in the process. I cannot figure out any big differences.
However, especially in warnings about over- or underfull \hbox I can clearly see differing values. Further, the `babel-package` creates differences. The following is added to the log on my laptop (which creates the smaller document).

```
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel)             in language  on input line 208.
 [259]
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "|
(babel)             in language  on input line 213.
```

I don’t have any idea how to solve these differences. Both installations are basically the same, yet the pdf files differ? I have not observed this behaviour for other (shorter) documents and could not reproduce the behaviour in a MWE. Are there further methods to investigate?

Comment: Can you check in your pdf viewers that both have the same page size? A4 vs letter could easily account for this, and a misclick on installation or texlive picking up different OS defaults (can't remember if texlive does this) could set a different default. Of course if the paper size is set in `\documentclass` that will override any default. Also check versions of packages used to set page sizes, and class files.

Comment: You can always minimize to a MWE. E.g. throw away the second half of the document. Do you get the same number of pages, or around 150 and 160? Or: stare at the pages and find the first one where they differ. And so on.

Comment: Show the log files.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I think I've used a PDF diff viewer, or at least one with synchronised scrolling, in the past. This may help the OP.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to the document and compare the version information in the file list at the end of the `log` files. Also be sure that you have installed the hyphenation patterns for the used languages on both machines.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I found the problem. I compared `\listfiles` output. Openoffice provides a good option to compare two documents (i.e. log files). I found out that I was using two different versions of `garamondx` font. Reverting to `lmodern` showed two identical documents. After update of garamondx, the docs are also identical.
@UlrikeFischer the entire log file is about 75 pages A4.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by two different versions of garamondx.